# File handling in Python triggerd by Java

Tags: java, python, windows

I would like to automate some tasks with Python Scripts. 
The basic application is written in Java. 
To trigger the Python stuff i use

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(PYLOCATION + " " + pyScript + " " + ARGS)
```

So at first im just trying to create a directory over the python script:

```
#! python3
import sys,shelve,os

filename = 'log.txt'
logfile = open(filename,'w')
path = sys.argv[1]
path = os.path.abspath(path)
logfile.write(str(path))
logfile.close()

if not os.path.exists(path):
   os.mkdir(path)
```

If i pass the path for the new dir as absolute path like

```
static final String ARGS = "G:\\SNMP_Tool\\PythonScripts\\defaultDataBase";
```

it works fine

If i pass it relative like

```
static final String ARGS = "..\\PythonScripts\\defaultDataBase";
```

it dosent work. (if i enter the string for the relative path in the python script directly it works)

Also is the logfile log.txt never written if the task starts from the Java App.

If i just hit the .py script twice with the mouse it writes the logfile as it should.

I think the problem to write the file could be the authorization from windows.

But why dosent it take the relative path over the argument string?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches I can think of:

1. In the Java script, resolve the file to absolute path before passing it to the Python script, or
2. Use a form of [exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-java.io.File-) which specifies the working directory:

   ```
   String[] args = {pyScript, ARGS};
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
           PYLOCATION,
           args, 
           new File("G:\....."))
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the tipps. 
The hint with the working directory was gold!

In my case i decieded to get these direct in the .py script with
        currentDir = os.getcwd()